# how to trigger updatepanel within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

i have an updatepanel in my asp.net web page. I want to trigger the updatepanel within a javascript function insead of triggering with a button. 
In order to do that, i used `__doPostBack('myUpdatePanel', '');` function. But i think it causes the whole page postback. My document.ready function is also executed when i call this function. I may be missing some points. 
Is there any other way to trigger updatepanel within a javascript function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think if you put a hidden button inside the update panel and you can use the javascript to fire the click of this button, it will do what you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Update_UpdatePaanel() {
            document.getElementById('<%= YourButton.ClientID %>').click()
        }
    </script>
```

The button MUST be inside a hidden div and DON'T set visibile="false" because if you set it to false, the control will not render and the javascript will produce errors.

```
<div style="display:none">
        <asp:Button ID="YourButton" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Comment: is it really possible? So i should look for how to fire click of a aspbutton. do you know how to fire click event of a hidden aspbutton with javascript?

Comment: document.getElementById('<%# YourButton.ClientID %>').click()

Comment: i used "<%=YourButoon.ClientID%>" insead of '<%# YourButton.ClientID %>'. it looks well now.

Comment: I had to put `CausesValidation="False"` on the button too

Comment: Tired of seeing this hack. Is there not a straightforward way by updating the control without the use of a button?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a javascript function and execute the generated postback event:

```
<%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(myUpdatePanel, "")%>
```

The above statement is put on your aspx page, and it references the exact same code generated from the server to cause a postback for your panel.  You can use it by putting it inside a function on the client side:

```
function fncUpdatePanel () {
    <%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(myUpdatePanel, "")%>;
}
```

Then you can attach that function to any event on your page (even a mouseover event).  This example uses a server side to attach the event:

```
myUpdatePanel.attributes('onmouseover', 'fncUpdatePanel()')
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail? i need to trigger panel in javascript code. your code seems to be in server side?

Comment: This doesn't work because GetPostBackEventReference is for postbacks not async post backs. I'm trying to use GetCallbackEventReference instead but not having any lucking passing it the correct control reference to make it work.

Comment: Can't access ClientScript on a custom ascx control