# General strategy for ASP.net web forms dashboard?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, svg

We have an existing ASP.NET Webforms website that we want to have a dashboard page for.

We want to have 10 individual homemade svg bar charts which each could be an independent user control ascx page. Initially we'd like the charts empty just with their chart title and axis displaying but with a "loading" animated gif. Once backend sql data is retrieved (could take time) we'd then plan to modify some of the svg code programatically to increase the height of the bars to reflect the data.

Can anyone advise on how we can we do this so that the underlying data isn't queried sequentially chart by chart but they are all queried at the same time (to save time) and whenever one has the data loaded then their loading gif disappears (can do with display:none) and their relevant svg updated?

Comment: Use ajax......?

Comment: @FrankerZ So would we a) put all the svg charts in asp update panels within their own ascx files, b) use document.ready in the main page to then trigger each of the 10 update panels to do a postback?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856315/how-to-trigger-updatepanel-within-a-javascript-function I think we can put hidden asp buttons in each update panel. I think we  set them each to conditional update according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155262.aspx so they don't update when other panels do. And start them all via JavaScript via document.ready. Would that be OK or is there a more preferred method?